# Why can I import linspace from scipy but in the doc it is from numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I tried to understand it by myself using the [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/index.html) , but I don't get why, from the module `scipy`, I can import `linspace` which is a function of the module `numpy`. They both work well. 
Also, I can't find it in the `scipy` doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scipy [imports all Numpy functions](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/__init__.py#L71) in its namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Granted, it is not easy to know where to find this in the documentation, but it is in the [first page of the tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/general.html) that is also the first section of the documentation.

> In addition, many basic array functions from numpy are also available
>   at the top-level of the scipy package.